# Where can I get a white search icon?

Tags: android, icons

I'm talking about the search icon used in many apps, such as Twitter (top right), Evernote (top right), Books (top right).

Here is the icon:  http://developer.android.com/images/icon_design/ic_menu_search.png

Where can I get this in white? Thank you.

Comment: @Anon, You can't use the bucket tool when there is fading.  I attempted it.  Looks terrible.

Comment: @Matthew - Zoom in more.

Comment: it is ic_menu_search icon in the framework. I.e. use @android:drawable/ic_menu_search to reference it.

Comment: @mach thanks for this answer. I was looking for same thing. Some people are so quick to flag stuff as off-topic. This was very very useful.

Comment: just check this : android.R.drawable.ic_search_category_default

Answer (score 4):

http://www.findicons.com/ is a great resource for this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks scunliffe, that is indeed a great resource.